# How would I remake compareTo method?

Tags: java, compareto

I have

```
public int compareTo(Object other)
{


}
```

I need to be able to compare two different sets of numbers and the numbers in the corresponding places.
For example:

```
Time t1 = new Time(17, 12);
System.out.println(t1);

Time t2 = new Time(9, 45);
System.out.println(t2);
System.out.println("Greater Than:");
System.out.println(t1.compareTo(t2));
```

And the output would be

```
1712
0945
Greater Than:
1
```

In the time class, the first number is hours while the second number is the minutes.  I need help comparing the two numbers.

My time class uses

> ```
> public Time (int y, int x)
> {
> minute = x;
> hour = y;
> if (minute>59 || minute<0)
> {
>  minute = 0; 
> }
> if (hour>=24 || hour<0)
> {
>  hour=0; 
> }
> ```
>
> }

How would i compare two new time objects to each other?

Comment: Please show your attempt (this looks suspiciously like an assignment for a class).

Comment: Show your `Time` class...

Comment: This is, I just need help starting.  Teacher was not very helpful explaining.  Got a 30 min explanation for compare class.  This is for highschool comp sci.  Also in the code i have time inplementing comparable.  Need help to override the old compareto whith this one.  Just need something to start with, and i can do the rest.

Comment: The logic has nothing technical.  Tell us verbally how you are doing the comparison in your mind when you faced 17:12 & 09:45.  If you can speak out in a systematic way, then there should be no problem writing it as code.

Comment: Well I want to compare each number to each other starting from the first number in the hour and check each digit after.  If in the first object the number is larger than the number in the second object it returns 1, if it's less return -1 and if equal, return 0.            Ex. 1 is checked against 0.  1 is larger, so the return is 1 and that's the end.  If the numbers are equal, then the second number is checked.

Comment: If the numbers are equal, then the return is 0 (bit of a typo in the other comment), and if the first number is smaller, -1 is returned.

Answer (score 1):

First implement the `Comparable` interface with the correct generic type, in your case `Comparable<Time>`.
Then you're able to access the other object's attributes.

Your method will now look like this:

```
public int compareTo(Time otherTime)
{
  //... compare things here... like:
  return hour.compareTo(otherTime.getHour());
}
```

This is a sample, you have to implement compare logic yourself, since I don't know if this is an assignment.

Answer (score 1):

The logic has nothing technical. Tell us verbally how you are doing the comparison in your mind when you faced 17:12 & 09:45. If you can speak out in a systematic way, then there should be no problem writing it as code.

I can understand you maybe a total newbie in programming that you have even no clue in writing a most simple line of code.  However in programming world, no one is gonna lead you by grabbing your hand to write.  You should try to solve it by yourself.

I won't give you a direct answer.  However, this is a little example of similar problem.  Assume there is a grading system like this, where `A1 < A2 < A3 ... < An < B1 < B2 < B3... < C1....`

What I am going to do the comparison is, first I will compare the alphabet part, if grade1's alphabet is larger/smaller than grade2's alphabet, I won't need to care about the number part, and I can return -1/1 according to the alphabet being smaller/larger.  If the alphabet is the same, then I need to compare the number part, and return 1,-1 and 0 depending on the result.

Then the code will look like something like  (half-psuedo code)

```
public class Grade implements Comparable {
    char level;  // A,B,C,D
    int sublevel;   // 1,2,3,4

    // ctor, getters/setters etc

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Grade other) {
        // compare the alphabet part
        if (this.level < other.level) {
            return -1;
        } else if (this.level > other.level) {
            return 1;
        }

        // alphabet not larger or smaller, that means equals

        // compare the number part
        if (this.sublevel< other.sublevel) {
            return -1;
        } else if (this.sublevel> other.sublevel) {
            return 1;
        } else {  // alphabet and number part are all equals
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

if you can understand what's going on here, then there should be no problem implementing your problem.  (Of course there is shorter and cleaner way to implement this.  However I think what you need is to learn the basics first)

Comment: Tell us verbally how you are doing the comparison in your mind when you faced 17:12 & 09:45. If you can speak out in a systematic way, then there should be no problem writing it as code - couldn't agree more!

Answer (score 0):

So your class is Time and i assume it has 2 variables one for minutes and one for seconds. What you need to compare is the t1.minutes to t2.minutes and the t1.seconds to t2.seconds. Your code however is missing a lot of parts and it can't really help us answer your question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the comparator interface on your Time class. 
Doc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

There should be plenty of examples online.